# How to add Dynamic GroupBy Column in Data Flow Aggregate Activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using the Data Flow(preview). My "Aggregate" activity requires a GroupBy column which is not dynamic. Hence, I cant group by that column. I just want to map the column by name.

For example:
These are the two schemas:
1) Columns: M Id, Date/Time, Data Type, Values
2) Columns: MID, Date, DataType, Units

Both have actually the same data type and structure. I want to GroupBy DataType and avg(units).

Because, the name of the one field is "Data Type" and other "DataType". How do I map it together.

I have created a "Derived" activity with this

Column: DataType
Expression: case(startsWith(toString(byPosition(7)), 'D'), toString(byName('Data Type')),toString(byName('DataType')))

But it doesnt work. Any help is highly appreciated.

I just want to know how do I map the column by name.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a dynamic expression directly in the Group by field in the Aggregate transformation. Hover over the Group By field and select "Computed Column" to enter into the Expression Builder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to determine whether to use the column "Data Type" or the column called "DataType"? If so, just enter your conditional expression directly into the expression builder on the Aggregate group by. Note that in your expression above, you are using byPosition() which is a numeric value for the number representing the incoming columns left to right, starting at position 1. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks a lot for getting back to me

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks a lot for getting back to me. Hi Mark, Thanks a lot for getting back to me. Actually, I dont have schema defined. There are two different types of schema but pointing to same data is coming from the blob. [link](https://imgur.com/a/cnrAWoX). I get this error GetCommandOutputAsync failed with Failure 2019-08-20 10:53:41.827 failed DebugManager.processJob, run=22b1d2b2-f5c3-40dc-8135-48e02f4980e7, errorMessage=DF-AGG-004 at Aggregate 'Aggregate1'(Line 9/Col 8): No columns specified - RunId: 22b1d2b2-f5c3-40dc-8135-48e02f4980e7

Comment: so for example: as per the image both Energy and Data Value are same but different column name pointing to same data from csv file. If the schema is not defined even sink doesnt recognise column name.

Comment: Let's have a look at the underlying script for your Data Flow design. Go to Code > Plan and then paste the DSL script behind your flow, if you don't mind.